# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

Tags: c#, oledb

For the following code, I am getting multiple step OLE DB operational error.

Error is thrown when Dataset is being filled by Adapter (on this line: `sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Tran");`)

```
OleDbCommand sCommand;
OleDbDataAdapter sAdapter;
OleDbCommandBuilder sBuilder;
DataSet sDs;
DataTable sTable;

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection = PEConnectionManager.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
connection.Open();

string sql = "Select * Frequency from Tran where frequency=?";
sCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
//string sfrequency = "Quarterly";
OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("Quarterly", OleDbType.VarChar);

sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("frequency",param);

sAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sCommand);
sBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
sDs = new DataSet();
sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Tran");      // Error is thrown here...
sTable = sDs.Tables["Tran"];
sCommand.Prepare();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure of your SQL syntax?

Comment: SQL is quite ok. Only think if parameter is removed from the query it works. But I need parameter